# How to escape the forward slash in the string in javascript? C# web api not recognizing the forward slash

Tags: javascript, c#, escaping, forward, slash

How do i escape forward slash in javascript ?
string str= "[B]Hello How are you[/B]".
This is the string i want to pass from client side to c# web api. 
C# web api  not recognizing forward slash in the string. - "[REM][TB]Hello How are you[%2FTB]"

Comment: [mcve], please.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below replace function to remove your escape sequences:

```
str.replace(/\//g, "");
```